# iframe tweet box share button cut off text after any special characters

Tags: iframe, twitter, share, tumblr, tweets

i'm making my tumblr blog & i'm having a problem when I created a share button using iframe.

the share button grabs my post title or photo alt and url from my blog and pastes it into the tweet box, but the problem comes in when there is "?" or " ' " sign in the post title and it just completely cuts off after that "?" sign in the share box.

For example:
if the title is: "Your value doesn’t decrease based on someone’s inability to see your worth" and the URL is "xxx"

it should grab both and paste them in their entirety into the share box but it cuts off at 
which happens to share in the box to be :

Your value doesn xxx via @{twitteraccount}

instead of :

Your value doesn’t decrease based on someone’s inability to see your worth xxx via {twitteraccount}

here's the iframe code:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?url={ShortURL}&via={twitteraccount}&text={PhotoAlt}&counturl={Permalink}" style="width:90px; height:20px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried `{URLEncodedPhotoAlt}` ?

Comment: What @Ally suggested would resolve the issue as `'` is ended the src value early. Also remember Twitters character limit is 140.